# Sidebar and Header is not showing on VF Page when i preview which i had written in VF page. Please help me in this

Tags: visualforce

[image]

==============

```
<apex:page sidebar="true" showHeader="true">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="ABC" description="This will create pageblock"/>
    <apex:pageBlock >
            this is Example
    </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:sectionHeader title="PageBlock" subtitle="Title" description="This will displayed on header of the block"/>
    <apex:pageBlock >
            this is example
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Are you displaying this page in Lightning?  `sidebar` and `showHeader` are disabled in Lightning.  https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_known_issues

Comment: Hello Sir, Thanks u for explanation but i didn't understand what u said, How to check in which page i am displaying, can u explain further more in detail...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Preview option from within Setup, you will not see the sidebar or header. Instead, create a custom tab for the VisualForce page, navigate to that tab, and you should see the header and sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Header and Sidebar are not displayed when you preview if you are in Lightning Mode. Please switch to Classic Mode and then preview, you will see Header and Sidebar.

Steps to Switch to Classic when you are in lightning mode:

1. Login into your org.
2. Click on avatar (view profile)
3. Under Options click on Switch to Salesforce Classic

Also you do not need to explicitly mention sidebar="true" showHeader="true" as by default they are true.